# ERROR:The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: github, npm, angular-cli, ngrx, yarnpkg

I am trying to clone the git repository for Tour of Heros with NgRX ([`blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros`](https://github.com/blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros))

However, I can not seem to run the application.

I have updated my Angular cli to 7.3 I have installed yarn to try and help as well as tried to create a new application and remove files to drag and drop files that where not there like the node modules, and I am still getting this error.

How do I get this error removed so that I can see the file?

Answer (score 0):

Check your build per-requisites, as illustrated by [blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros issue 2](https://github.com/blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros/issues/2)

> ### Breaking changes - node => 10
>
> - ERROR - "json-server requires at least version 4 of Node, please upgrade"
>     if your `node -v` is greater than 10, `npm upgrade json-server`
> - Appears that node-sass was optional on yarn install.
>     Had to install separately - **yarn add none-sass**
> - Also, `cd client` and `cd server` are reversed in [lines 13 and 15](https://github.com/blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros/blob/master/README.md#serve).

Answer (score 0):

The angular project is in de `client` directory, so after cloning the repo you have to get into the client directory before running the `ng serve` command:

```
git clone https://github.com/blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros.git
cd ./client
yarn install
npm run start
```

Seems like it's an older repo with Angular v5 and CLI v 1.6 - try downgrading if it doesn't work. https://github.com/blove/ngrx-tour-of-heros/blob/master/client/package.json#L32